# movckmvc test that correct error message returned

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, integration-testing, mockmvc

The following test (testing that validation fails as the terms and conditions accepted by the user is not latest version) works fine but I would like to test the error message that's returned. The reason for this is a subsequent test (check that validation fails if accepted terms and conditions version is null) will have the same test criteria.

As a result I would also like to test the error message that's returned. I've spent the whole morning searching for somethign and cannot find anything which makes me wonder whether it's even possible to access/test error message values? I can see it's within the Model but am struggling to access/test it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

S

**TEST**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({ "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml" })
public class FailureRegistrationControllerTest {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
}

@Test
public void acceptedVersionIsNotTheLatestTest() throws Exception {

    //Create the DTO User
    UserRegistrationDTO user = TestingUtility.createMinimumUserDTO();
    user.setTermsAndConditionsVersion(TestingConstants.NOT_LATEST_TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS);

    //Run the test
    ResultActions resultActions = TestingUtility.buildResultsActionsMinimum(mockMvc, user);

    resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk()); 
    resultActions.andExpect(view().name("register"));
    resultActions.andExpect(model().attributeHasFieldErrors("user", "termsAndConditionsAccepted"));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve similar problem once but I have only not very official solution. I have checked the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-test/3.2.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/ModelResultMatchers.java#ModelResultMatchers.attributeHasErrors%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) how they are doing it and I have found out that any errors are stored inside the model prefixed with `BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX`, see their code:

```
private BindingResult getBindingResult(ModelAndView mav, String name) {
    BindingResult result = (BindingResult) mav.getModel().get(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + name);
    assertTrue("No BindingResult for attribute: " + name, result != null);
    return result;
}
```

so you are able to obtain it from model and check details...